# Eclipse perspective problems || org.eclipse.ui.* || org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow

Tags: java, eclipse, window, settings, eclipse-luna

I created my own view and I've problems viewing it.

1. on every start I've to switch to another perspective and switch back (so it doesn't load *itself?*)
2. I've many errors in the view "error log" from Eclipse and I don't know what to do
3. The icons in the status bar are also a bit strange (see screenshot)

[Files (Eclipse Log and Screenshot)](http://ralaweb.bplaced.net/txt/private/report/eclipselog/141210_1058)
[image: Screenshot]

*log has to many characters*

### UPDATE 1

after selecting in appearance classic the problem with the icons is gone :D

Comment: Please add the logs and screenshot to the question. Or at least the logs if you lack reputation for adding the screenshot.

Comment: log has to many characters

Comment: I think SO will automatically make it scrollable. Try it.

Comment: oh sry, yes I know; I mean SO doesn't support so many chars..